# Find and replace a string in Python

Tags: python

I have a string like this:

```
 line = "Student   =  Small   |1-2|   Student"
```

I want to replace this line to

```
 line = "StudentShort  =  Small  |1-2|    StudentShort"
```

The problem is I don't know wheither first and last words are `Student` or anything else in string. I mean it can be `Men`, `Women`, `Teacher` anything.

I only know that if there is `small` in string I have to replace first and last word with that name and short

Can some one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add "Short" to the first and last word of the string...My advice would be to split and then use indexing and then join!

```
In [202]: line = "Teacher   =  Small   |1-2|   Student"

In [203]: line = line.split()

In [204]: line[0] += "Short"

In [205]: line[-1] += "Short"

In [206]: line = "  ".join(line)

In [207]: line
Out[207]: 'TeacherShort  =  Small  |1-2|  StudentShort'
```

I think it would be useful to have this in a function:

```
def customize_string(string,add_on):
    if "small" in string:
        line = string.split()
        line[0] += add_on
        line[-1] += add_on
        return "  ".join(line)
    else:
        return string
```

here is using it to show that it works!

```
In [219]: customize_string(line,"Short")
Out[219]: 'TeacherShort  =  Small  |1-2|  StudentShort'
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know what are my first and last word in string

Comment: Your question is unclear then and this satisfies your example...so what you're saying is that you want to be able to replace an instance without knowing what it is first?

Comment: Yes, The problem is I don't know what my first and last word is in the string, it can be teacher, or men or women anything

Comment: OH, so your question isn't all cases in student, it is for the first and last word? And is the string formatted where everything is separated by 2 spaces?

Comment: `str.split` won't preserve the irregular spaces in the string.

Comment: I am pretty sure that those are typos though. As he did say yes when I asked if the string is formatted by a separation of two spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this using `regex`:

```
>>> line = "Student   =  Small   |1-2|   Student"
>>> if re.search(r"\bSmall\b",line):
    print re.sub("^(\w+)|(\w+)$",lambda x:x.group()+"Short",line)
'StudentShort   =  Small   |1-2|   StudentShort'

>>> line = "Men   =  Small   |1-2|   Men"
>>> if re.search(r"\bSmall\b",line):
    print re.sub("^(\w+)|(\w+)$",lambda x:x.group()+"Short",line)
'MenShort   =  Small   |1-2|   MenShort'
```

An improved version of above code(as suggested by @thg435):

```
def solve(strs, match, word):
    if re.search(r"\b{0}\b".format(match), strs):
         return re.sub(r"(^\w+|\w+$)","\g<0>{0}".format(word), strs)

>>> solve("Men   =  Small   |1-2|   Men", "Small", "Short")
'MenShort   =  Small   |1-2|   MenShort'
>>> solve("Student   =  Small   |1-2|   Student", "Small", "Short")
'StudentShort   =  Small   |1-2|   StudentShort'
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know what are my first and last word in string

Comment: Just `\1Short` instead of lambda.

Comment: @thg435 I tried that before using `lambda` but it returned `'\x01Short` and with raw string it raised error.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: interesting. You might want to change the expr to `(^\w+|\w+$)` or use `\g<0>` in replacement to denote the group 0.

Comment: you forgot to answer the whole question! He only needs to add "Short" if the string contains "small"

Comment: @RyanSaxe Well the question is poorly formatted, btw that can be handled by a simple `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the String replace method in python..

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace

```
    string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])
    Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring
    old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is 
    given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know what are my first and last word in string

Comment: You can find it by splitting the string and getting the first and last word p.split()[0] (give first) splitListCount=len(line.split());
last=line.split()[splitListCount-1];

Answer (score 0):

This selects the "Student" part based on the equals-sign by splitting the string. then it replaces it using line.replace.

```
line = "Student   =  Small   |1-2|   Student"
name = line.split('=',1)[0].strip()
line = line.replace(name,name+'Short')
print line
```